# OnePlus and Huawei detect "Disable Data Usage" enabled for my app

Tags: android, huawei-developers, oneplusone

Apparently on a OnePlus and Huawei devices a user can disable data usage on a single app.
The feature is located on a onePlus in `Settings/apps & notifications/[app name]/Mobile data & Wi-Fi`

If enabled the app will not get mobile data no matter what.

I am not aware of other brands where this is possible.

Is there a way to detect this has been enabled?